Conda always resetting connection on updates and installs
I am trying to create some new envs with conda which has worked fine for me until now.
Now I get the "connection reset by peer" error whenever I try to do basically anything.
It also shows that I am still on conda 4.x and should update to 25.5, the thing is, I can't update conda since I always get that error.
Does anyone have a feasible workaround? I can't lose my environments.

please provide the full stacktrace instead of partial errors.
